# Not able to return proper response after insert

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm using Node.js/Express.js to install data to my MySQL DB.
Inserting data works fine, but returning success / fail gives me an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
```

This is my code:

```
var crud = {
  newProject: function (req, res, callback) {
    db.query('INSERT INTO projects SET ?', req.body, function(err, res) {
      // This is where it fails
      if(err){
        return res.status(500).json({error: err});
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({success: 'Insert row success'});
      }
    });
  },
}

// Express routing
app.post('/project/*', crud.newProject);
```

What am I not getting right here?

**Solution**
So this is what I used to make it work (after changing 'res' to 'resp' as suggested):

```
  if (err) throw err;
  res.end(JSON.stringify({response: 'Success'}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your defining `res` twice. The express response object is getting overwritten by the data param in your node callback.

Try the following (see comment)

```
var crud = {
  newProject: function (req, res, callback) {
    // changed 'res' to 'resp' to avoid collision with Express' 'res' object
    db.query('INSERT INTO projects SET ?', req.body, function(err, resp) { // here's your error 
      // This is where it fails
      if(err){
        return res.status(500).json({error: err});
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({success: 'Insert row success'});
      }
    });
  },
}

// Express routing
app.post('/project/*', crud.newProject);
```

If you define error-handling middleware functions after the last `app.use()` in your main configuration

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500).send(err.message || 'Internal server error.')
})
```

You can use the `next` callback as a catchall error handler, so the above would then become

```
var crud = {
  newProject: function (req, res, callback) {
    db.query('INSERT INTO projects SET ?', req.body, function(err, resp) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      return res.json({success: 'Insert row success'});
    });
  },
}

// Express routing
app.post('/project/*', crud.newProject);
```

`res.json()` by default should add a `200 Success` code to the response header. Ideally you would want to inspect the `resp` data param from the node callback after checking the state of `err` to properly handle the response and proceed accordingly, especially if you are dealing with last evaluated records associated with a continuation token usually provided in the response which some DBALs and APIs do for you and some don't. Either way you will want to be sure additional recursion isn't necessary to fetch remaining records before responding successfully.

Comment: My problem is that `res.whatever` returns error message that it is undefined :/

Comment: See the above edits, notice the comments I added? Your defining `res` twice. You just need to change the naming convention your callback params are using.

Comment: Yes and I changed `res` to `resp` as you suggested. Still got the error. But changing how I return the result made it work. So thanks :)

Comment: Fyi, if memory serves me right, simply calling `res.json({success: 'Insert row success'})` would have resulted in the same. If you have appropriate middleware injected after defining routes, you could have returned the result of the invoked callback instead of throwing the error. See edits, I think this would have been  a better solution, it's been awhile since I've used Express ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `res` object is undefined as it is not returning any response after the insert. You may return a new object like:

`return {
  status: 200,
  json: {success: 'Insert row success'}
}`

Comment: How do you know if it was a success or not? ;-)

Comment: Because the ``err`` object is undefined.

Comment: Yes, dcd018's respond looks more accurate.